# Why does the following line fails in spark and how can i fix it?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
sc.parallelize((1 to 10).map(i => if(i % 2 == 0) Some(i) else null)).toDF()
```

This line fails with the following error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType$ cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:414)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.rddToDataFrameHolder(SQLImplicits.scala:155)
      ... 50 elided
```

I am trying to understand why does it fail and how can I fix it.

Comment: Hey!! Has any of the answers helped you?

Answer (score 2):

A scala `Int` cannot be null. Therefore, to create a spark dataframe containing an int column with null values, you have two options:

```scala
// either use Option[Int], whose "null value" is None and not null
sc.parallelize((1 to 10).map(i => if(i % 2 == 0) Some(i) else None)).toDF()

// or use java Integers
sc.parallelize((1 to 10).map(i => if(i % 2 == 0) new Integer(i) else null)).toDF()
```

NB1: You can be more compact with spark implicits:

```scala
import spark.implicits._
(1 to 10).map(i => if(i % 2 == 0) Some(i) else None).toDF()
```

NB2: For your use case, you can also use the `range` function:

```scala
spark.range(1, 11).select(when('id % 2 ===0, 'id).otherwise(0) as "value")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sc.parallelize((1 to 10).map(i => if(i % 2 == 0) Some(i) else None)).toDF()
```

Option Null value is **None**

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to map the integer values to DataFrame Directly, that is the possible error, that is why it is giving casting error, typecast error. First try to collect the Output and then try to map it to a dataframe.

collect the values first of all in a var, by calling on the parallelized job  .collect()

see something like this - which will help in mapping the values to the columns of df that you are trying to create.

val someDF = Seq(
  (8, "bat"),
  (64, "mouse"),
  (-27, "horse")
).toDF("number", "word")

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't think collect is needed.